# PHP bulk insert foreach

Tags: php, mysql

I have a curl script which reads the data from a remote source. Below is the current code:

```
function download_page($path){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
    $retValue = curl_exec($ch);                      
    curl_close($ch);
    return $retValue;
}
$sXML = download_page('http://remotepage.php&function=getItems&count=100&page=1');
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);
foreach($oXML->results->item->item as $oEntry){
    $insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_item (first_name, last_name, date_added) VALUES ('" . $oEntry->firstname . "', '" . $oEntry->lastname . "', '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "')");
}
```

The script works however is extremely slow to insert as I imagine its because its writing each individual record. The count variable is how many records returned for each page and the page variable is a simple page counter.

I am wondering if there is a way to do a bulk insert statement to insert all 100 records at once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Are you sure its the `INSERT` that is slow and not the `cURL` request? Try `echo`ing some timing out to the page to make sure you know where its slowing down.

Comment: Please go through this http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: You can add multiple records in one insertion with the code that @magnetik, @chauhan or @Repox have provided. Or you can use prepared statements, that will help against SQL Injections (or use `mysql_real_escape_string`) and precompile the query so it will be faster if you execute multiple `INSERT` statements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this within one statement by doing something like this :

```
$sXML = download_page('http://remotepage.php&function=getItems&count=100&page=1');
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_item (first_name, last_name, date_added) VALUES";
foreach($oXML->results->item->item as $oEntry){
    $query .=  "('" . $oEntry->firstname . "', '" . $oEntry->lastname . "', '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "'),";
}
mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: Remove the last comma from `$query` before inserting it to the database: `$query = substr($query, 0, -1);`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
foreach($oXML->results->item->item as $oEntry){
  $inserts[] = "(". implode(', ', array ($oEntry->firstname, $oEntry->lastname, date("Y-m-d H:i:s") ) ) .")";
}
$insert_query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tbl_item (first_name, last_name, date_added) VALUES ".implode(', ', $inserts));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all records at once as below: Like when we export data from mysql table.

```
INSERT INTO tablename (id, field2, field3, field3) VALUES ('', 5454, '454', '545'), ('', 'erwe', 'rewrew', 'werew'), ('', 'ewrew', 'rwerwe', 'werwer'), ('', 'jkj', 'ere', 'uju') , ('', '343', '3434', 'dfdf');
```

Answer (score 0):

to bulk insert operation you can append you script in a variable and you can run this as whole but for this you have to use `mysqli_multi_query`. Check this link http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php