# Bulk Insertion in Laravel using eloquent ORM

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How can we perform bulk database insertions in Laravel using Eloquent ORM?

I am working with an XML document, looping through its elements. I want to accomplish something like this in Laravel:

```php
$sXML = download_page('http://remotepage.php&function=getItems&count=100&page=1');
$oXML = new SimpleXMLElement($sXML);
$query = "INSERT INTO tbl_item (first_name, last_name, date_added) VALUES";
foreach($oXML->results->item->item as $oEntry){
    $query .=  "('" . $oEntry->firstname . "', '" . $oEntry->lastname . "', '" . date("Y-m-d H:i:s") . "'),";
}
mysql_query($query);
```

but I am getting the following error.

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters.

Comment: Do you have a `has_many` relationship on your models?

Comment: @jonathandey no i dont have any relationships at the moment

Comment: @DavidBarker i have tried forming the quesr string using a for loop. I have also tried using transactions in laravel.

Comment: @AramBhusal Could you post up your code? I'm sure I have some code here that will help you.

Comment: Have you seen http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent#mass-assignment?

Comment: @DavidBarker I have tried this approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615762/php-bulk-insert-foreach and used pdo instance to prepare and execute satement. I am running into SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Comment: @BenjaminRH mass assignment is automatically assigning inputs to a single model's fields, it is not about creating multiple models at once.

Answer (score 442, accepted):

You can just use `Eloquent::insert()`.

For example:

```
$data = [
    ['name'=>'Coder 1', 'rep'=>'4096'],
    ['name'=>'Coder 2', 'rep'=>'2048'],
    //...
];

Coder::insert($data);
```

Comment: Does this still apply to Laravel 4?

Comment: @advait: yes, it still applies to Laravel 4.

Comment: @Ola where is the insert method located? I can't seem to find it in the Model access class: http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html

Comment: @advait sorry, not been here in a while. check http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Query.Builder.html

Comment: Worth noting that it doesn't touch `Eloquent` in fact. It just proxies the call to `Query\Builder@insert()` method. There's no way to efficiently insert multiple rows with Eloquent, nor does it offer any method for bulk inserts.

Comment: Please note that if you use i.e. `Model::insert(array($model1->toArray(), ...))`, that `->toArray()` won't present you with a flat array of attributes if your model has relations or casts. You could look into `->getArrayableAttributes()`, but you don't get the timezones... In short; there's no nice way of doing this.

Comment: How to save if I have two foreign keys in one table and I want multi insert, it should insert foreign ids as well automatically using Eloquent, I'm using Laravel 5.

Comment: @CanVural what should we do to update/create timestamps also?

Comment: How can we get all the IDs of newly inserted rows?

Comment: @GTF what if there occur a problem at a starting record, In this case records after this problematic record will be inserted into db?

Comment: This will use one insert. So, given a big enough array, it will fail.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk is right, and that makes the model based call a misleading abstraction because it bypasses things like $fillable and the model events such as creating, created...  It all gets skipped.

Comment: Yes, you need to be careful with this one.

Comment: @MilanMaharjan you can simply set the created_at, updated_at fields manually in the array you pass to Model::insert()

Comment: it does adds values to `created_at` and `updated_at` i have tried and verified.

Comment: @SagarAhuja I just tried the same, it does not insert "created_at" and "updated_at" values automatically - maybe you set them manually.

Comment: How can I get inserted IDs using this?

Comment: still applies to laravel 9. inserts what would be over 45 seconds for 4000 rows in 1 second. your mileage of course will vary.

Comment: I appreciate your advice, and while it works great with only the insert operation, it would be helpful if someone could advise me as to if there is a way to update or insert data using a batch array.

Answer (score 102):

We can update GTF answer to update timestamps easily

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'name'=>'Coder 1', 'rep'=>'4096',
        'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'modified_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
       ),
    array(
         'name'=>'Coder 2', 'rep'=>'2048',
         'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
         'modified_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
       ),
    //...
);

Coder::insert($data);
```

Update:
to simplify the date we can use carbon as @Pedro Moreira suggested

```
$now = Carbon::now('utc')->toDateTimeString();
$data = array(
    array(
        'name'=>'Coder 1', 'rep'=>'4096',
        'created_at'=> $now,
        'modified_at'=> $now
       ),
    array(
         'name'=>'Coder 2', 'rep'=>'2048',
         'created_at'=> $now,
         'modified_at'=> $now
       ),
    //...
);

Coder::insert($data);
```

UPDATE2: for laravel 5 , use `updated_at` instead of `modified_at`

```
$now = Carbon::now('utc')->toDateTimeString();
$data = array(
    array(
        'name'=>'Coder 1', 'rep'=>'4096',
        'created_at'=> $now,
        'updated_at'=> $now
       ),
    array(
         'name'=>'Coder 2', 'rep'=>'2048',
         'created_at'=> $now,
         'updated_at'=> $now
       ),
    //...
);

Coder::insert($data);
```

Comment: Or use Carbon in the beginning of the script to define a `$now` variable: `$now = Carbon::now('utc')->toDateTimeString();`. Then just use `'created_at' => $now, 'updated_at' => $now` for every insertion.

Comment: How can we get all the IDs of newly inserted rows?

Comment: Why 'utc'? Is it project's preferency, or, does eloquent always work in 'utc'?

Comment: Do not use 'utc' if you want to use your server's datetime, otherwise you'll be using the 'Coordinated Universal Time'. In most of the cases you'll want to save the data in your local time. Then use Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()

Comment: I don't want to start a huge "spaces vs. tabs" argument, but please, save timestamps in UTC! It will save you a huge amount of pain later on! Think about users globally :)

Comment: If I may ask, what's the big need for `Carbon` in this situation? What's wrong with `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`?

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo they use it to handle conversion to UTC instead of local time() and manual calculation.

Comment: @iSS Not only globally -- just think about your users in other cities and states!

Comment: Was missing `use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 45):

This is how you do it in more Eloquent way,

```
    $allinterests = [];
    foreach($interests as $item){ // $interests array contains input data
        $interestcat = new User_Category();
        $interestcat->memberid = $item->memberid;
        $interestcat->catid = $item->catid;
        $allinterests[] = $interestcat->attributesToArray();
    }
    User_Category::insert($allinterests);
```

Answer (score 30):

To whoever is reading this, check out [`createMany()` method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L294).

```
/**
 * Create a Collection of new instances of the related model.
 *
 * @param  array  $records
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 */
public function createMany(array $records)
{
    $instances = $this->related->newCollection();

    foreach ($records as $record) {
        $instances->push($this->create($record));
    }

    return $instances;
}
```

Comment: This is not what's called bulk insert. Because of the poor implementation, this function will prepare and execute the same query once per Item.

Comment: It's worth noting this is a relationship method, can cannot be called directly from the model i.e. `Model::createMany()`.

Answer (score 9):

I searched many times for it, finally used custom `timestamps` like below:

```
$now = Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString();
Model::insert([
    ['name'=>'Foo', 'created_at'=>$now, 'updated_at'=>$now],
    ['name'=>'Bar', 'created_at'=>$now, 'updated_at'=>$now],
    ['name'=>'Baz', 'created_at'=>$now, 'updated_at'=>$now],
    ..................................
]);
```

Answer (score 6):

`Eloquent::insert` is the proper solution but it wont update the timestamps, so you can do something like below

```
 $json_array=array_map(function ($a) { 
                        return array_merge($a,['created_at'=> 
                                            Carbon::now(),'updated_at'=> Carbon::now()]
                                           ); 
                                     }, $json_array); 
 Model::insert($json_array);
```

The idea is to add created_at and updated_at on whole array before doing insert

Answer (score 1):

From Laravel 5.7 with `Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder` you can use insertUsing method.

```
$query = [];
foreach($oXML->results->item->item as $oEntry){
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
    $query[] = "('{$oEntry->firstname}', '{$oEntry->lastname}', '{$date}')";
}

Builder::insertUsing(['first_name', 'last_name', 'date_added'], implode(', ', $query));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$start_date = date('Y-m-d h:m:s');        
        $end_date = date('Y-m-d h:m:s', strtotime($start_date . "+".$userSubscription['duration']." months") );
        $user_subscription_array = array(
          array(
            'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
            'user_subscription_plan_id' => $request->input('subscription_plan_id'),
            'name' => $userSubscription['name'],
            'description' => $userSubscription['description'],
            'duration' => $userSubscription['duration'],
            'start_datetime' => $start_date,
            'end_datetime' => $end_date,
            'amount' => $userSubscription['amount'],
            'invoice_id' => '',
            'transection_datetime' => '',
            'created_by' => '1',
            'status_id' => '1', ),
array(
            'user_id' => $request->input('user_id'),
            'user_subscription_plan_id' => $request->input('subscription_plan_id'),
            'name' => $userSubscription['name'],
            'description' => $userSubscription['description'],
            'duration' => $userSubscription['duration'],
            'start_datetime' => $start_date,
            'end_datetime' => $end_date,
            'amount' => $userSubscription['amount'],
            'invoice_id' => '',
            'transection_datetime' => '',
            'created_by' => '1',
            'status_id' => '1', )
        );
        dd(UserSubscription::insert($user_subscription_array));
```

`UserSubscription` is my model name.
This will return "true" if insert successfully else "false".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more Laravel way to solve this problem is to use a collection and loop it inserting with the model taking advantage of the timestamps.

```
<?php

use App\Continent;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class InitialSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        collect([
            ['name' => 'América'],
            ['name' => 'África'],
            ['name' => 'Europa'],
            ['name' => 'Asia'],
            ['name' => 'Oceanía'],
        ])->each(function ($item, $key) {
            Continent::forceCreate($item);
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry for my misunderstanding. For bulk inserting this could help and maybe with this you can make good seeders and optimize them a bit.

```
<?php

use App\Continent;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class InitialSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $timestamp = Carbon::now();
        $password = bcrypt('secret');

        $continents = [
            [
                'name' => 'América'
                'password' => $password,
                'created_at' => $timestamp,
                'updated_at' => $timestamp,
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'África'
                'password' => $password,
                'created_at' => $timestamp,
                'updated_at' => $timestamp,
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Europa'
                'password' => $password,
                'created_at' => $timestamp,
                'updated_at' => $timestamp,
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Asia'
                'password' => $password,
                'created_at' => $timestamp,
                'updated_at' => $timestamp,
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Oceanía'
                'password' => $password,
                'created_at' => $timestamp,
                'updated_at' => $timestamp,
            ],
        ];

        Continent::insert($continents);
    }
}
```

Comment: This makes one query per item. It's not a bulk insertion.

Comment: @EmileBergeron I agree with you. I have edited my post so maybe this could help to have good bulk inserting. Considering leaving the tasks that take a lot of time out of the loop (carbon, bcrypt) this can save you a lot of time.

Comment: @FranciscoDaniel
I appreciate your advice, and while it works great with only the insert operation, it would be helpful if someone could advise me as to if there is a way to update or insert data using a batch array.

Answer (score -3):

You can Create on by one and get return collection of created instance of model

```
  $createdCollection= collect([
            ['name' => 'América'],
            ['name' => 'África'],
            ['name' => 'Europa'],
            ['name' => 'Asia'],
            ['name' => 'Oceanía'],
        ])->map(function ($item, $key) {
            return Continent::create($item);
        });
```

Comment: I think this isn't bulk insert

Answer (score -4):

For category relations insertion I came across the same problem and had no idea, except that in my eloquent model I used Self() to have an instance of the same class in foreach to record multiple saves and grabing ids.

```
foreach($arCategories as $v)
{                
    if($v>0){
        $obj = new Self(); // this is to have new instance of own
        $obj->page_id = $page_id;
        $obj->category_id = $v;
        $obj->save();
    }
}
```

without "$obj = new Self()" it only saves single record (when $obj was $this)

Answer (score -6):

Problem solved... Alter table for migrate

```
$table->timestamp('created_at')->nullable()->useCurrent();
```

Solution:

```php
Schema::create('spider_news', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('source')->nullable();
    $table->string('title')->nullable();
    $table->string('description')->nullable();
    $table->string('daterss')->nullable();

    $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();
    $table->timestamp('updated_at')->useCurrent();
});
```