# Inserting into a table from the array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am getting this array from the view

When i do `return $BlogData['Tag'];`

The result is

```
 ["1", "2"]
```

How can i insert this into each record i.e., a fresh entry in the table ?

```
S.No | Tag
   3 |  1
   4 |  2
```

Like the above given in the table

When i try

```
foreach ($BlogData['Tag'] as $x) 
        {
        echo $x;
        Tag::create($x);
        }
```

I am getting this error

```
message: "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::create() must be of the type array, string given,
```

Comment: i think the message is already clear for you to solve,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
foreach ($BlogData['Tag'] as $x) 
{
    Tag::create(['Tag' => $x]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For Model::create() the argument must be array. You have passed a single value not an array. Please have a look http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_create

For create method you have to $fillable array in your model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'Tag'
];
```

In your controller

```
$data = $BlogData['Tag'];
foreach ($data as $key=>$value)
{  $data_attribute = array('Tag'=>$value);
   Tag::create($data_attribute);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($BlogData['Tag'] as $x) 
{
    # Tag index will be the table column name
    # and its value is $x
    $pass = array(
        'Tag' => $x
    );
    Tag::create($pass);
}
```

here is a good link of nice way to insert multiple rows
using laravel

[Bulk Insertion in Laravel using eloquent ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm)