# Insert multiple values on multiple rows

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a form that has a dropdown where the user can select up to 5 countries.

I have two related tables, `users` and `countries`, where each user can have multiple countries selected.

The `users` table:

```
+----+----------+----------------------+
| id | username |     description      |
+----+----------+----------------------+
|  1 | user1    | Some description.    |
|  2 | user2    | Another description. |
+----+----------+----------------------+
```

The `countries` table:

```
+----+---------+---------------+
| id | user_id |    country    |
+----+---------+---------------+
|  1 |       1 | Canada        |
|  2 |       1 | United States |
|  3 |       1 | France        |
|  4 |       2 | Spain         |
|  4 |       2 | Italy         |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

As you can see, the country dropdown values should each have their own row in the table.

Here is my `UserController` so far (it only inserts into the `users` table for now):

```
$user = new User;
$user->username = Input::get('username');
$user->description = Input::get('description');
$user->save();
```

How would I insert multiple dropdown values such that each has its own row? What should my models look like for this to work?

Comment: I think you should have 3 tables here, users (list of users), countries (list of countries) and a user_country (the mapping between users and countries)

Comment: That's not something I require in the design. It's still besides the point though and doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Reading the [Laravel Eloquent Relationships Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships) should point you in the right direction.

Comment: From the description in your question you have a **one-to-many** relationship, and for that you **do** need a pivot table for mapping relations like @Dhiraj Bodicherla pointed out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bulk Insertion in Laravel using eloquent ORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm)

Answer (score 0):

If you're gonna use eloquent to do it, here's a suggestion:

//in your User model

```
public function countries()
{
     return $this->hasMany('Country');
}
```

//insert from the controller

```
$countries = json_decode(Input::get('countries'), true); //assuming you use json to submit the multiple countries

$user_countries = array();
foreach($countries as $country)
{
    $user_countries[]=new Country(array('country'=>$country));
}

//save the countries into the DB
$user->countries()->saveMany($user_countries);
```

for more info, do refer to the documentation:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#inserting-related-models