# How to insert multiple rows from a single query using eloquent/fluent

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following query:

```
  $query = UserSubject::where('user_id', Auth::id())->select('subject_id')->get();
```

and as expected I get the following result:

```
[{"user_id":8,"subject_id":9},{"user_id":8,"subject_id":2}]
```

Is there a way of copying the above result into **another table** so that my table looks like this?

```
ID|user_id|subject_id
1 |8      |9
2 |8      |2
```

The problem I have is that the `$query` can expect any number of rows and so im unsure how to iterate through an unknown number of rows.

Comment: in case anyone still needs it: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1295#issuecomment-193025045

Answer (score 446, accepted):

It is really easy to do a bulk insert in Laravel using Eloquent or the query builder.

You can use one of the following techniques.

```php
$data = [
    ['user_id'=>'Coder 1', 'subject_id'=> 4096],
    ['user_id'=>'Coder 2', 'subject_id'=> 2048],
    //...
];
```

1. Eloquent approach:

```php
Model::insert($data); // calls mutators including timestamps
```

2. Query Builder approach:

```php
DB::table('table')->insert($data); // does not call mutators
```

Comment: I've tried that but unfortunately it's recognising my result as an object and not an array

Comment: Use the ->toArray() method on the object collection.

Comment: It does not insert the timestamps.

Comment: add 'created_at'=>date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'modified_at'=> date('Y-m-d H:i:s') into your array.

source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26569967/1316842

Comment: I wonder why Laravel doesn't have something like 'createMany' for this.

Comment: I believe this approach will not trigger on_save and on_create event handlers declared it the "boot" method.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby the OP wanted to do a batch `INSERT`. The `HasOneMany::saveMany()` doesn't do that. **Eloquent** [sources are self-explainatory](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L234)

Comment: What if i have an array like this ` $array = ["54928328", "Carrie","Swift"]; ` ?

Comment: How do I retrieve the ids?

Comment: This technique is not inserting the created date. What should i do to insert created data with it? @KreshnikHasanaj

Comment: @Luvias Not a very _Eloquent_ solution, but you could create a `insertGetIds` method, that just iterates over each element in the array of arrays and calls `insertGetId` and pushes that ID to an array, and then return that array of IDs.

Comment: i tried ->toArray() as well but still it considers the collection as object.
```
 $data =DB::table(DB::raw('users'))->select('name','id','email')->where('name','like','Abdulh%')->orderBy('id')->get();
```
   DB::table('staff')->insert($data);

Comment: what to do when my array size is bigger than 10 thousands?

Comment: In this case of multiple records insertion, can i add a condition which checks if the id field value already exists in db table then that record will not be inserted. Please help. Eloquent updateOrCreate method works only for 1 record.

Comment: This is the most applicable answer! How do we put this in DB:transaction?

Answer (score 37):

using Eloquent

```
$data = array(
    array('user_id'=>'Coder 1', 'subject_id'=> 4096),
    array('user_id'=>'Coder 2', 'subject_id'=> 2048),
    //...
);

Model::insert($data);
```

Comment: insert is method of query builder. Accessor and mutators will not work with this insert

Answer (score 8):

**It is really easy to do a bulk insert in Laravel with or without the query builder.
You can use the following official approach.**

```
Entity::upsert([
    ['name' => 'Pierre Yem Mback', 'city' => 'Eseka', 'salary' => 10000000],
    ['name' => 'Dial rock 360', 'city' => 'Yaounde', 'salary' => 20000000],
    ['name' => 'Ndibou La Menace', 'city' => 'Dakar', 'salary' => 40000000]
], ['name', 'city'], ['salary']);
```

Comment: I could be mistaken but isn't this version 8 only?

Comment: laravel doc on [upsert](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#upserts) = update or insert.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/38938 this is one of the issue you'd face.