# DB::table Vs Eloquent Model - Laravel Database Seed

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, convention

When researching for Database Seeder, it's common to see people using `DB::table('my_table')->insert(['column' => 'value'])` in the Seeder classes. I'd like to know the reasoning behind this apparent convention as to why I *should* use `DB::*` instead of `MyModel::*` to perform such tasks.

Comment: I updated my answer with a note about model factories. I prefer the simple seeds because they're fast, but model factories are a good way to use Eloquent when seeding

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most importantly, because with `DB` inserts, you can do multiple inserts at once. Especially when seeding many large tables, that's much, much faster than doing one query per insert.

http://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#inserts

```
DB::table('users')->insert([
    ['email' => 'taylor@example.com', 'votes' => 0],
    ['email' => 'dayle@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
]);
```

You also don't need to load the Eloquent class or any of the bulk that comes with it. Again, seeding thousands of rows, creating thousands of Eloquent objects... that can take up a lot of memory.

And finally, if there do happen to be bugs or issues with the Eloquent models, your seeds will still work.

---

There are some downsides. For example if one of your Eloquent models overrides a setter to manipulate and format data before being saved, then you lose that convenience.

And actually, that applies to any model with $timestamps; with `DB` inserts you'll have to set the `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps manually. But with a seeder, you might want to simulate that items were created days or months or years ago, in which case you wouldn't **want** those timestamps to be set automatically.

---

But actually, a lot of people do use [model factories](http://laravel.com/docs/master/seeding#using-model-factories). If you do want to use your setters, or automatically assign relationships, and basically take advantage of everything Eloquent offers, then they're great to use for seeding. With the efficiency tradeoffs I mentioned, but sometimes that's worth it.

Comment: This is a good answer, however, according to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29723968/2905274) it should also be possible to use `MyModel::insert(...)` to insert many values just like in your example. Wouldn't this suggest that maybe `DB::Table()` should be deprecated in favor of more simplicity?