# How can I send scraped DATA to Mysql table with LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, scrape

I scraped some data with php and I want to send it to Mysql from Laravel. I connect to mysql but I don't know how to send it.

here is my scraped code;

```
$servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "laravel-test";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) 
    {

        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

    } 

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"https://suumo.jp/ms/shinchiku/osaka/sa_osaka/");
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
    curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1); 
    $sonuc = curl_exec($curl); 

    preg_match_all('@<div class="cassette-price">(.*?)</div>@si',$sonuc, $new);
    preg_match_all('@<ul class="cassette-plan">(.*?)</ul>@si',$sonuc, $info);
    preg_match_all('@<div class="cassette-header">(.*?)</div>@si',$sonuc, $name);


    $name = $name[0];
    $new = $new[0];
    $info = $info[0];


    for($i=0; $i < count($info);$i++)
    {
    echo $name[$i];
    echo $info[$i]; 
    echo $new[$i];  
    }
```

Thanks for help!!!

I am using laravel 5.7 by the way.

Comment: Why you can not send that data using laravel?

Comment: I don't know how to send scraped data by using laravel. That's the problem begins. I connect laravel to database and making tables but don't know how to send scraped data into that I created table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand, you can just add the data to a regular table

First, you can create a table (you've already done it, according to the comments)

Then add configuration to Laravel [https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database]

> The database configuration for your application is located at
>   `config/database.php`. In this file you may define all of your database
>   connections, as well as specify which connection should be used by
>   default. Examples for most of the supported database systems are
>   provided in this file.

Then use Laravel database to add the data

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show a list of all of the application's users.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
      for($i=0; $i < count($info);$i++)
      {
        DB::insert('insert into users (name, info, new)
        values (?, ?, ?)', [1, $name[$i], $info[$i], $new[$i] ]);
```

You could also add data to an array, and insert it once :

```
for($i=0; $i < count($info);$i++)
{
           $data[] =[
                    'name' => $name[$i],
                    'info' => $info[$i],
                    'news' => $news[$i],
                   ];  
}
DB::insert($data);
```

(see [Insert Multiple Records At Once With Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39113682/insert-multiple-records-at-once-with-laravel/39389935) )