# Laravel insert in one to many relationship

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have **Post** table and **images** table that have one to many relationship.

> Post Model Code

```
public function images()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\PostImage');
    }
```

I take from the user 3 images and I want to insert them in the images table with the post id.

> For example

**firstImage.jpg** with post id **1**

**secondImage.jpg** with post id **1**

**thirdImage.jpg** with post id **1**

> Question is

How I insert the three images at the same time with id 1 in **three columns**

> What I have tried

I have made a for loop that insert 3 times in the table but I know it is not a good practice and here is the code.

```
for($x = 0; $x < 3; $x++) {
$image = new PostImage;
$image -> post_id   = $ad -> id;
$image -> image     = $images_name[$x];
$image -> save();
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert multiple rows from a single query using eloquent/fluent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this approach if you need to insert just 3 images. However, if you want to insert hundreds of images, I'd recommend you to use the `insert()` method which will create just one query instead of creating 100 queries for inserting 100 images:

```
$array = [];
foreach ($images_name as $name) {
    $array[] = ['post_id' => $ad->id, 'image' => $name];
}
PostImage::insert($array);
```

Comment: they wont be more than 3 images so what is the best solution in this case?

Comment: @Frank for 3 images I'd stick with your solution, but I'd change the code to something like `foreach ($image_name as $name) { PostImage::create(['post_id' => $ad->id, 'image' => $name]); }`