# How do i store an array in model and controller with this javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

Im using laravel guys
here my

> index.blade.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var x =0;  
        $(".add-row").click(function(){
           x++;
           $("table > tbody").append('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="MFI" placeholder="Major Final Output" id="MFI" value="Participate in school activities">'); 
        }); //add input box
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: i want a dynamic txtbox to be saved in my controller and model with this javascript .

Comment: `$mfi=$request->mfi; foreach($mfi as $mf){ $model=new Model(); $model->attribute=$mf; $model->save();}`

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an solution**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 0;  
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
       x++;
       $("table > tbody").append('<input class="form-control" type="text" name="MFI[]" placeholder="Major Final Output" id="MFI'+x+'" value="Participate in school activities">'); 
    }); //add input box
});
```

> **NOTE :** Check `table > tbody` is exists in your HTML.

Comment: Yes! You can save the values of dynamic fields with name `name="MFI[]"`. @Pyo

Comment: After adding dynamic fields, Submit the form and debug the `REQUEST` in your Controller. @Pyo

Comment: This URL can be helpful for saving multiple Data in Laravel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent , You just Prepare the Form Data before Save. @Pyo