# Add column name to array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
[
    [
        "302260",
        "302250",
        "302248",
    ],
    [
        "Bruce Willis",
        "Jackie Chan",
        "Gary Oldman",
    ],
]
```

I need insert multiple this values, I found this answer: [How to insert multiple rows from a single query using eloquent/fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29723968/6678345), but I don't know how I can add column name to my array, to make it look like this:

```
[
    [
        "user_id" => "302260",
        "user_id" => "302250",
        "user_id" => "302248",
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Bruce Willis",
        "name" => "Jackie Chan",
        "name" => "Gary Oldman",
    ]
]
```

I can't use [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), because I have different values in the key: `1, 2, 3`

Answer (score 2):

An array key needs to be unique within an array. e.g. you can't have multiple keys called user_id within a single array. What you can do instead is have an array in the following format:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 1
            [name] => User1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 2
            [name] => User2
        )
)
```

That's also what the answer you're linking to describes.
The php code for the above array looks like this:

```
$users = array(
  1 => array("user_id" => 1, "name" => "User1"),
  2 => array("user_id" => 2, "name" => "User2"),
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I convert my array, but now I don't know how i can change key `1,2,3` to name of column `user_id` and second array `name`: http://iv.pl/images/50813748968996167864.png I need have this: http://iv.pl/images/46100388856337307172.png

Comment: the array in the second picture doesn't work as the keys aren't unique. if you want named keys you'll have to use the format I showed you in the second example. you can then use a loop to get the name and if of each user.