# Php File content into Multiple Talbes

Tags: php, mysql, json, insert, laravel-5.4

I have a File with over 360.000 Rows, every line is a JSON.

i read the Json into Php Variables and insert it into two Tables

"movies" and "movies_details"

i'm using Laravel 5.4.
My Problem is the Performance. 
so i can insert round about 35-40 rows in one minute with this code

```
$idMovie = DB::table('movies')
   ->insertGetId([
       'moviedb_id' => $id,
       'adult' => $adult,
       'created_at' => $dateTime,
  ]);
  DB::table('movies_title')
      ->insert([
          'movie_id' => $idMovie,
          'original_title' => $original_title,
          'created_at' => $dateTime,
      ]);
```

but i thing anyone know a faster and better way to insert this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: MySQL supports multi insert like so `INSERT INTO movie_title (movie_id, original_title, created_at) VALUES(1, 'title', '2017-11-14'), (2, 'title', '2017-11-14')`.... and so on.. this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent

Comment: Have you looked into the `chunk` method?

Comment: @RaymondNijland yes i have seen this link. My Problem with this link is:
they have only one table to insert there datas. but i need the inserted ID from the "Movie"-Table to assign it with the rows in "movie_details"-Table

Answer (score 0):

you could use multiple insert (bulk insert) assuming you can assign your vars an array

as in flat sql

```
    insert into your_table (moviedb_id, adult, created_at)
    values ($id[0],  $adult[0], $dateTime[0]), 
            ($id[1],  $adult[1], $dateTime[1]),

            ......
            ......
            ($id[n],  $adult[n], $dateTime[n])
```

in this way with  each insert you insert more rows  and instead  of 30 - 40 for minute you can insert 30*n - 40*n rows

so check for yout ORM or framework query manager for the equivalent function