# insert multiple records at once in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have multidimensional array and I want to insert all the data in one query with my model, I know I can do it with `DB` query builder class, like

```
 DB::table('table')->insert([ 
     ['name' => 'foo'],
     ['name' => 'bar'],
     ['name' => 'baz']
 ]);
```

but how can I do it with model? 
 `Model::create()` doesn't insert multiple records, also I don't want to insert items with loop. is it possible to do this with eloquent?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert multiple rows from a single query using eloquent/fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent)

Comment: @Webinion that answer says there is an Eloquent way to do that. You can use `Model::` syntax, but still, QB method will be used.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, its correct way to insert multiple data, there is not problem with that.

Comment: @Webinion the point is there is no an Eloquent solution.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, yes, it is an Eloquent solution, here `Model::` shows Eloquent in that answer

Comment: @Webinion Eloquent is not about using `Model::` syntax, but about events, accessors, mutators, relationships, casting etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this with model:

```
Model::insert([ 
   ['name' => 'foo'],
   ['name' => 'bar'],
   ['name' => 'baz']
]);
```

But here insert is the same QB method.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone else coming here, make sure you use a multi-dimensional array of arrays. I was a dummy and trying to just do `Model::insert(array(), array())` instead of `Model::insert(array(array(),array()));`... just one of those moments...

Comment: @daisura99 You have to fill those manually since it's using the query builder and not Eloquent. So each line you're inserting needs to have something like:
`'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
'updated_at' => Carbon::now(),`

Comment: but it will fail if one of the column didn't exist in db, while `create` will "filter" it so it won't throw error column not found. how to prevent this?