# How to upload a csv file containing large records into database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, csv, import, upload

I am trying to upload a .csv or .xls file that contains about 10,000 records. For the first attempt, the function/code below reads the csv file and were able to insert about **1600 rows/records into the transactions table in ~2 minutes,** without the code line: **set_time_limit(0);** And i got: *Maximum execution timeout* error

On second attempt, now with the code: **set_time_limit(0);** This time around, ***10,000 records were inserted in ~11 minutes*.**

My questions now are:

1.How can I read a csv/xls file and insert its records/rows which is >= *10,000*, into database in Laravel app, very fast?

2.The practice, **'set_time_limit(0)'**, I used here, is it a good one? Is there a better way I can go about this?

3.Before reading and insertion takes place, is there away i can determine the time/maximum time it could take to complete the operation/execution?

```
public function importDataSet(Request $request)
{

    if(Input::hasFile('file')){
        $file = Input::file('file');
        $uname = uniqid();
        $oname = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $filename = $uname.$oname;
        //create a folder, data-sets, if not exist in the public folder
        $filelocation = 'data-sets';
        $filepath=$file->move($filelocation, $filename);

        ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings', TRUE);

        $header = '';
        $rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file($filepath));
        $header = array_shift($rows);
        $csv = array();
        set_time_limit(0);//reset maximum execution time to infinity for this function
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $csv[] =  $row;//Is not used
            //eturn $rows;
            $transaction = new Transaction;
            $transaction->dataset_id = 1;
            $transaction->itemsets=json_encode($row);
            $transaction->save();
        }
    }else{
        //noting here
    }
    return 'Success';
}
```

Comment: Don't know how exactly works but this needs to data queue.

Comment: You should try to turn this into a queueable job, and return `202` as status code for the request itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is, in my opinion, one of the big disadvantages of an active-record ORM like Eloquent. Now you're executing a database query for every record you save, which inherently is 10,000 queries.

One easy way to solve it is by using `mysqlimport`, since you have a .csv file anyway. This mostly applies to one-off uploads though.

Another is to use the `insert()` commands of your model or query builder. There's already a great answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent) that pretty much directly answers your question.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer solve the problem. The reading and insertion of the **10,000** records now took about: 13 seconds