# Add multiple rows while migration

Tags: laravel, database-migration, laravel-5.6, laravel-migrations

I am wondering is there a way to make 10-50 rows as default rows that could be added after migration in database?

In case I need to use `php artisan migrate:fresh` its pain to add simple values over and over again. Like I have Countries table where I need to add over and over again when I run migrate:fresh...

OR

Can I somehow exclude some tables from others that would be affected with command lines

Like inside create_countries_table:

**DO_NOT_TOUCH_THIS_TABLE**

Thanks

**UPDATE:**

Without routes etc. Just by migrations

Comment: use seeding. [Laravel seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding)

Comment: I think that will do it

Comment: Multiple rows at once : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has a great system about that, all you need to use database seeders.

For exaple you have a users table and you want to make some users.

First create a seeder using `make:seeder` command

```
php artisan make:seeder UsersTableSeeder
```

Then open your UsersTableSeeder and add these lines

```
public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name' => str_random(10),
            'email' => str_random(10).'@gmail.com',
            'password' => bcrypt('secret'),
        ]);
    }
```

Then open your DatabaseSeeder class and add this line

```
public function run()
{
     $this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);
}
```

and run `db:seed` command

```
php artisan db:seed
```

For more further check out the [seeding](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/seeding) on laravel docs