# How can I store request array without using foreach in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an array in the post request as an example below:

```
$data = array(
    array('title'=>'1st title', 'desc'=>'desc'),
    array('title'=>'2nd title', 'desc'=>'desc'),
    array('title'=>'3rd title', 'desc'=>'desc'),
)
```

Is there a way in Laravel using Eloquent I can save above data without using foreach? Note that the array keys which I am getting in the request is not same as column names of the table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert multiple rows from a single query using eloquent/fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent)

Comment: Its not, it is a little different, please check description again.

Comment: So can you tell us what are column names which are relevant to request keys so that we can map it to?

Comment: request array has 'title' key and db column is article_title. Same goes for other four columns, I think I still have to run a foreach to make the mapping data as per table schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this would help you

```
$data = [
    ['title' => '1st title', 'desc' => 'desc'],
    ['title' => '2nd title', 'desc' => 'desc']
    .....
];

DB::table('users')->insert($data);
```

Put all the values you want to insert in to an array and then pass it to the insert function.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#inserts

Comment: i believe the array keys has to be the table column names which is not in my case, column names are different then the array keys and to make above array, I think I still have to run a foreach.

Comment: if the keys are different yes, you need to use foreach

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using eloquent: just as mentioned by Sethu, but a few lines will be:

```
Model::insert($data); // eg: Posts::insert($your_request_array);
```

Just pass in the array directly here: above will return true on success.