# How to store the user id into the company_policy_users table by using looping method?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

my name is andy and i'm new to Laravel, I would like to ask how to store my user id into the new table which table name ( company_policy_users ) by using looping method ? Can anyone help me out ? Thank you so much
Here is my controller coding

```
foreach ($array as $selectedUser){
        $policyUser = new $policyUser([
            'policy' => $request->get('id'),
            'user_id' => $selectedUser,
            'read' => 0
        ]);
        $policyUser->save();
```

My database name = ( company_policy ) with table name -  ( company_policy_users ) :
The column we have inside the ( company_policy_users ) table 
1. id = (bigint)
2. user_id = (int)
3. policy_id = (int)
4. read_by = ( Boolean )
5. date_read = (datetime)

Comment: please can you edit your question and be more specific, so we can help? where are you performing the loop? you should post your blade, route and controller code

Answer (score 1):

Let Define that your model like

```
CompanyPolicy
CompanyPolicyUser
```

There are a lot of way to insert multi record. it would be better if you provide your view and controller code.
But looking to your code I will using Model::insert($arrData);

```
$policyUsers = [];

foreach ($array as $selectedUser){
    $policyUsers[] = [
        'policy_id' => $request->id,
        'user_id' => $selectedUser,
        'read' => 0
    ];
}

if(count($policyUsers) > 0) {
    CompanyPolicyUser::insert($policyUsers);
}
```

[Insert Multi Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent)

Thank and hope it can help.