# Selecting Array from multidimensional array and save into db table

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am trying to list and then insert into a SQL table from this array :

SQL table :

```
id  time    average_position    search_visibility_index click_potential
```

data is :

```
Array
(
    [name] => average_position
    [series] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-18
                    [1] => 36.27
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-19
                    [1] => 36.23
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-20
                    [1] => 36.18
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-21
                    [1] => 36.07
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-22
                    [1] => 36.53
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-23
                    [1] => 36.65
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-24
                    [1] => 36.21
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-25
                    [1] => 36.08
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-26
                    [1] => 35.87
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-27
                    [1] => 35.53
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-28
                    [1] => 34.6
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-29
                    [1] => 34.19
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-30
                    [1] => 34.11
                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-31
                    [1] => 34.08
                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-01
                    [1] => 33.09
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-02
                    [1] => 33.03
                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-03
                    [1] => 32.96
                )

            [17] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-04
                    [1] => 32.64
                )

            [18] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-05
                    [1] => 33.08
                )

            [19] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-06
                    [1] => 33.03
                )

            [20] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-07
                    [1] => 32.83
                )

            [21] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-08
                    [1] => 33.02
                )

            [22] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-09
                    [1] => 32.75
                )

            [23] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-10
                    [1] => 32.27
                )

            [24] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-11
                    [1] => 32.18
                )

            [25] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-12
                    [1] => 30.64
                )

            [26] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-13
                    [1] => 30.6
                )

            [27] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-14
                    [1] => 30.56
                )

            [28] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-15
                    [1] => 30.53
                )

            [29] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-16
                    [1] => 30.1
                )

            [30] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-17
                    [1] => 29.86
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [name] => search_visibility_index
    [series] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-18
                    [1] => 5.14
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-19
                    [1] => 5.14
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-20
                    [1] => 5.36
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-21
                    [1] => 5.44
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-22
                    [1] => 5.01
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-23
                    [1] => 5
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-24
                    [1] => 5.01
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-25
                    [1] => 5.03
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-26
                    [1] => 4.07
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-27
                    [1] => 5.23
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-28
                    [1] => 4.48
                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-29
                    [1] => 4.57
                )

            [12] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-30
                    [1] => 5.72
                )

            [13] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-31
                    [1] => 5.66
                )

            [14] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-01
                    [1] => 5.9
                )

            [15] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-02
                    [1] => 5.99
                )

            [16] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-03
                    [1] => 6.1
                )

            [17] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-04
                    [1] => 6.01
                )

            [18] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-05
                    [1] => 6.09
                )

            [19] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-06
                    [1] => 5.95
                )

            [20] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-07
                    [1] => 5.99
                )

            [21] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-08
                    [1] => 6.04
                )

            [22] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-09
                    [1] => 5.96
                )

            [23] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-10
                    [1] => 6.15
                )

            [24] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-11
                    [1] => 5.29
                )

            [25] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-12
                    [1] => 5.6
                )

            [26] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-13
                    [1] => 6.64
                )

            [27] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-14
                    [1] => 6.62
                )

            [28] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-15
                    [1] => 6.61
                )

            [29] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-16
                    [1] => 6.66
                )

            [30] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-04-17
                    [1] => 5.53
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [name] => click_potential
    [series] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-18
                    [1] => 70.73
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-19
                    [1] => 70.74
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-20
                    [1] => 73.77
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-21
                    [1] => 74.89
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-22
                    [1] => 74.35
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-23
                    [1] => 74.19
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-24
                    [1] => 74.34
                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-25
                    [1] => 74.71
                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-26
                    [1] => 60.46
                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-27
                    [1] => 77.58
                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2020-03-28
                    [1] => 66.51
                )

            [11] => Array
               …
```

Question is how to save these data with single mysql query as there are multiple arrays. But all of them are based on fixed date time queries.

foreach($contents_series as $avg_array){

```
DB::table('data_series')->insert(
    ['time' =>$avg_array[0],'average_position' =>$avg_array[0]['url_series'][0]['series'][1]]
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to bring the array to the format in the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent). If the dates present and are the same for all arrays, the task is quite trivial - each entry for the date must contain three entries - 'average_position', 'search_visibility_index' and 'click_potential' with corresponding values.

This means that you have to go through each array, take the date from element #0, use it as a key, and add the corresponding array key with its value under element 1.

```
 <?php

 $yourFirstArray = ['name' => 'average_position', 'series' => [['2020-03-18', 36.27], ['2020-03-19', 36.23]];
 $yourSecondArray = ['name' => 'search_visibility_index', 'series' => [['2020-03-18', 5.14], ['2020-03-19', 5.14]];
 $yourThirdArray = ['name' => 'click_potential', 'series' => [['2020-03-18', 70.73], ['2020-03-19', 70.74]];

 $average_position_series = $yourFirstArray['series'];
 $search_visibility_index_series = $yourSecondArray['series'];
 $click_potential_series = $yourThirdArray['series'];

 $data = [];

 foreach($average_position_series as list($date, $value)) {
     $data[$date]['average_position'] = $value;
 }

 foreach($search_visibility_index_series as list($date, $value)) {
     $data[$date]['search_visibility_index'] = $value;
 }

 foreach($click_potential_series as list($date, $value)) {
     $data[$date]['click_potential'] = $value;
 }

 DB::table('mytable')->insert($data);
```

Comment: yes the dates are the same for all arrays, i am trying to understand your solution

Comment: Added the three arrays for easier understanding