# bulk insert the Array still Considered as Object NOT DUPLICATE

Tags: laravel

i try the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent)  about bulk insert in laravel Query builder.
my query output is

```
[
 {"name":"Dayle","id":1,"email":"dayle213@gmail.com"},
 {"name":"John","id":2,"email":"john.doe@gmail.com"}
]
```

but when i try

```
   DB::table('staff')->insert($data);
```

i get error Query\Builder::insert() must be of the type array, object given,

when i try

```
   DB::table('staff')->insert($data->toArray());
```

i get error Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string.

how can i insert inn bulk ?

Comment: as in the previous Q with the below data it does work
[{"name":"Coder 1","id":4096,"email":"email@example.com"},{"name":"Coder 3","id":43,"email":"emqqqqail@example.com"},{"name":"Coder 3","id":33,"email":"ezzzmail@example.com"},{"name":"Coder 4","id":11,"email":"emawil@example.com"}]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$data` is encoded as JSON object, you need to decode it to make an array:

```
$data = json_decode($x, true); // array
DB::table('staff')->insert($data);
```

Comment: Could you expand this, to explain what this does, rather than just giving the command?

Comment: @Andrew this is the output http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a7f25d5bdec6d2b6d2bc9421668b5c5a150c7ae

Comment: Understood.  But to be a useful SO answer, we're after explanation and detail.  Thanks.