# Insert multiple data into database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have a form that user can insert multiple data into database. Here is the form look like[image: form for input data]

On my **blade view** file, I write something like this

```
<div class="mb-3 table-responsive">
 <table class="table table-striped" id="program_details">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th scope="col">Umur</th>
    <th scope="col">Detail Program</th>
    <th scope="col"> </th>
   </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <input type="number" class="form-control" id="umur" name="umur[]" value="{{ old('umur') }}" required>
    </td>
    <td>
     <textArea class="form-control" id="detail_program" name="detail_program[]" style="height: 100px;" required>{{ old('detail_program') }}</textArea>
    </td>
    <td>
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="addRow()">Add</button>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

For my controller file, I just do this for now

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all());
}
```

After I run the code, I got the data that I wanted, but I don't know how to insert it into database. Here is what I got from the user input

```
[ "nama_program" => "wertyuio"
  "umur" => array:3 [
    0 => "4"
    1 => "9"
    2 => "6"
  ]
  "detail_program" => array:3 [
    0 => "dfghjnbvcdrtyui"
    1 => "ertyjnbvcxdty"
    2 => "ertyjnbvcxdrtyu"
  ]
]
```

Just for the record, that `umur` and `detail_program` is belong to another database table named `program_details` and the `nama_program` is belong to `program_vaksins`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert multiple rows from a single query using eloquent/fluent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723865/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-from-a-single-query-using-eloquent-fluent)

Comment: @KGG it help a little, but not entirely solve my problem. Thank you for the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This setup is not that good since you are grouping ids with ids and values with values instead of id with values.

Anyways, you want to use nested foreach

```
foreach($array['umur'] as $umur) {
    foreach($array['detail_program'] as $program) {
        Model::create([
            'umur' => $umur,
            'detail_program' => $program
        ]);
    }
}
```

**EDIT FOR DUPLICATED DATA IN DB**

Hmm, not 100% sure but this might work just fine :)

```
foreach($array['umur'] as $key => $umur) {
    Model::create([
        'umur' => $umur,
        'detail_program' => $array['detail_program'][$key]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I will try your solution for now. I hope its work for me

Comment: Hi man, I just want to let you know that you solution is working, but its inserting each data twice to the database. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @Untitled99 hello, I am glad it is working, at least partially hehe 

I have edited my answer, can you please try it?

Comment: Thanks for the new answer. I'll try it for now

Comment: Hey man, thank you for the new answer. It's work very good. No more duplicate data. Thank you very much.