# Bulk insertion of array of eloquent models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Is it possible to insert several eloquent models in one query?

Let's say I have eloquent model `Page` and I want to insert array of pages or collection of pages in one query

```
$page1 = new Page();
$page2 = new Page();
$pages = [
  $page1,
  $page2,
];
or
$pages = Collection([$page1, $page2]);
```

I want something like

```
$pages->save();
```

But it warns that "Method save does not exist".

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm), but there they insert array of arrays and I want to insert array of eloquent models.

Comment: I think this is not possible. Check this: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1295

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `saveMany()` option.

This example might work for you:

```
DB::table('pages')->saveMany($pages);
```

And if you are working with relationships you can even use a "cleaner" way (just showing you example of ways to use this function):

```
$book = App\Book::find(1);

$book->pages()->saveMany([
    new App\Page(['title' => 'A new page.']),
    new App\Page(['title' => 'Another page.']),
]);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, saveMany() doesn't work as you expected in the first example.