# how to insert bulk data at a time in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, bulk

Hi all I am trying to insert multiple rows in a database at a time. Currently I can only save a single row at a time.
I have done following:

```
public function addNewPriceRevision($data){
$PriceRevision=new ProductPriceRevision(
    [
        'product_id'=>$data->product_id,
        'invent_price'=>$data->invent_price,
        'revised_price'=>$data->revised_price,
        'effective_date'=>$data->effective_date,
        'deleted'=>$data->deleted,
        'remark'=>$data->remark,
        'user'=>$data->user,
        'date'=>$data->updated_at,

    ]
    );
 $PriceRevision->save();
 return Common::getJsonResponse(true, 'new price revision created successfully!', 200);
}
```

Comment: Please check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert all objects to arrays and then create an array from multiple arrays:

```
$data = array($data1->toArray(), $data2->toArray());
```

If you need to add timestamps, you must do it manually:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$data1 = $data1->toArray();
$data1['created_at'] = $date;
$data1['updated_at'] = $date;

$data2 = $data2->toArray();
$data2['created_at'] = $date;
$data2['updated_at'] = $date;

$data = array($data1, $data2);
```

Then you could use [mass assignment](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment) feature to create rows:

```
ProductPriceRevision::create($data);
```

And don't forget to fill `$fillable` array inside `ProductPriceRevision` model:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'product_id',
    'invent_price',
    'revised_price',
    'effective_date',
    'deleted',
    'remark',
    'user',
    'updated_at'
];
```