# Can it possible to save the array as a record in table using eloquent in laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using eloquent model and there is json request which contains array and i am prossessing it using foreach like folloeing:

```
public function save(Request $request){
  $i = 0;
  $flag = 1; 
  foreach ($request->all() as $record) {
    if($flag){
      $flag = 0;
      continue;
    }
    else{
      $user = \App\barcodedb::create($record);
    }
  }
}
```

**is it the correct way to save the record from array?**

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$request_data = $request->all();
$data = json_decode($request_data['data']);
```

Store array in $data and use it

Comment: But I dont want this. what i want is to extract one array from large json and save it directly in database table like i did above

Comment: What you answered me is already i have implemented successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for a foreach loop. After the JSON is converted to an array, you can just parse this array as the only argument in the insert method, like this:

```
App\barcodedb\insert($data);
```

Laravel will automatically recognize such an array as an array containing multiple new records.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13595393