# Why are there issues creating many related records related in larevel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have two related tables: *table A* and *table B*.

### model a

```
public function comments(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\tableB');
}
```

### model b

```
public function posts()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\tableA');
}
```

I want create a record in *table A*, then use it and insert many records in *table B*.

This code works :

```
$s = tableA::create(["postname" =>"test"]); // this create success
```

now I insert records of comments for this created post:

```
$s->comments()->createMany([["txt"=>"a"],["txt"=>"b"]]);
```

**Question 1 :**

I enabled query debug and see this code :

```
$s->comments()->createMany([["txt"=>"a"],["txt"=>"b"]]);
```

runs a query for each insert (i.e. `insert into x values (a)` and `insert into x values (b )` and ........) !!!

**How can the code be changed such that it will not run one Insert statement for each record?!**

**Question 2 :**

I have a problem with passing an array to the laravel `createMany()` method :(.

How can this output `[["txt"=>"a"],["txt"=>"b"]]` be created with php?

I tried to create with below code but its not working and laravel shows an error

```
  $b = array();
        array_push($b,"txt","yellow");
        array_push($b,"txt","ssss");
```

Can anybody help me?

i want Exactly this : [see the link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) (The createMany Method ) --- but it run multi query for each insertion

```
$post = App\Post::find(1);

$post->comments()->createMany([
    [
        'message' => 'A new comment.',
    ],
    [
        'message' => 'Another new comment.',
    ],
]);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk Insertion in Laravel using eloquent ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm)

Comment: no this is normal insertion not relationship

Comment: i want Exactly this : [https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models) (The createMany Method
)  --- but it run multi query for each insertion :( how to fix this?

Comment: It is by design that Laravel will do this... https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/HasOneOrMany.php#L264

Comment: YES i dont want edit laravel :D but i want Alternative way :( do u have any suggest ?