# Saving multiple records in a laravel eloquent create

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to save multiple records via

```
AppSettings::create(
    [
        'name' => 'mail_host',
        'type' => $emailsettingstype->id,
        'value' => '',

    ],
    [
        'name' => 'mail_port',
        'type' => $emailsettingstype->id,
        'value' => '',    
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'mail_username',
        'type' => $emailsettingstype->id,
        'value' => '',
    ],
);
```

But from the above, only the first array is getting created. Where am i going wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 29):

I think this should do

```
AppSettings::createMany([
    [
        'name'=>'mail_host',
        'type'=>$emailsettingstype->id,
        'value'=>'',

    ],
    [
        'name'=>'mail_port',
        'type'=>$emailsettingstype->id,
        'value'=>'',

    ],
    [
        'name'=>'mail_username',
        'type'=>$emailsettingstype->id,
        'value'=>'',
    ],
]);
```

Make sure you're passing an *array of arrays*, not a **params of array**.

UPDATE, you can use `Model::insert()` although according to what I've read, that  method doesn't create/update the timestamps.

Comment: This answer was for an earlier version of Laravel, unfortunately, I'm no longer up to date and not sure how this should be done in the latest major version. Id appreciate if someone would actually update this, if that adds any value though.

Comment: Call to undefined method App\Models\Post::createMany() , Version 8 of laravel

Comment: Model::insert() works on Laravel 7

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

This advice does not work for version 9 or any previous Laravel version. 

According to the official Laravel documentation, the method createMany() does "create multiple related models", meaning it works only on related models, not on the model directly, as written above.

Answer (score 25):

You can just use Eloquent::insert() [link](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_insert) as below:

```
AppSettings::insert([
    [
        'name'=>'mail_host',
        'type'=>$emailsettingstype->id,
        'value'=>'',

    ],
    [
        'name'=>'mail_port',
        'type'=>$emailsettingstype->id,
        'value'=>'',

    ],
    [
        'name'=>'mail_username',
        'type'=>$emailsettingstype->id,
        'value'=>'',
    ],
]);
```

The problem with above is that it won't update timestamps, find examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm)

Comment: Note: `Model::insert()` does not store `created_at` and `updated_at`, so you should add them yourself if needed.

Answer (score 5):

The Create many Method `createMany` is available on relationship check reference to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339658/how-to-insert-multiple-records-with-createmany-method-in-laravel) and this [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) from laravel

so far my example look like this.

I have two models `Pricing` and `AvailableService` Model

Pricing Model

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Pricing extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ["name", "price"];
    public function available(){
        return $this->hasMany(AvailableService::class, "pricing_id", "id");
    }
}
```

And the `AvailableServiceMode` look like this

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class AvailableService extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ["pricing_id", "service_id"];
    public function service(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Service::class, "service_id", "id");
    }
}
```

So `createMany` operation look like this

```
$insertMany = Pricing::create(['name'=>request('name')]);
$insertMany->available()->createMany([
      ['service_id'=>1],
      ['service_id'=>2],
      ['service_id'=>3],
      ['service_id'=>4],
      ['service_id'=>5],
]);
```

And it works for, you can give it a try too. THANKS

Comment: create many works but its still executing too many sql queries. is there something like insert for relations?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to store multiple record in seeder use this method instead of `insert` because in my case I want to slug automatically created using `spatie/laravel-sluggable` pkg. If you used the `insert` or `DB` technique then you have to give the value for `slug` field also.

## CategorySeeder

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Servcategory;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CategorySeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $categories = [
            [
                'name' => 'Automotive',
                // 'slug' => 'automotive',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Business Services',
                // 'slug' => 'business-services',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Computer, Telecom & IT Services',
                // 'slug' => 'computer-telecom-&-it-services',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Education & Training',
                // 'slug' => 'education-&-training',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Finance',
                // 'slug' => 'finance',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Hospitals, Clinic, Medical',
                // 'slug' => 'hospitals-clinic-medical',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Real Estate, Construction, Property',
                // 'slug' => 'real-estate-construction-property',
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'Travel,Toursim & Hotels',
                // 'slug' => 'travel-toursim-&-hotels',
            ],
        ];

        // Servcategory::insert($categories);
        collect($categories)->each(function ($category) { Servcategory::create($category); });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case some one searching for eloquent model, I used the following method:

```
foreach($arCategories as $v)
{                
    if($v>0){
        $obj = new Self(); // this is to have new instance of own
        $obj->page_id = $page_id;
        $obj->category_id = $v;
        $obj->save();
    }
}
```

`$obj = new Self();` is a must otherwise it only saves single record when `$this` is used.

Answer (score -2):

in seeder create an array and do foreach with Model::create(). All your records will be with timestamps

```
protected $array = [
    [...],
    [...],
    [...]
];

public function run()
{
    foreach ($this->array as $value) {
        Model::create($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Dude it's incorrect, because for example if had 100000 records, it has to run 100000 queries and it's so harmful and terrible for your project