# How to insert multiple records with createMany method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to create multi record with createMany , how can i insert array to this method Without Data replication ?

```
 public function update(Request $request, Question $question)
    {
        $options = $request->only('title', 'description', 'question_id');

        $options_data = [];

        foreach ($options as $key => $value) {

            $options_data[] =[
                'title' => $options[$key],
                'description' =>$options[$key],
                'question_id' => $options[$key]
            ];

        }

        $question->options()->createMany($options_data);
```

result: dd()
i submit 2 record with 3 fields

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "option one"
      1 => "option two"
    ]
    "description" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "option one"
      1 => "option two"
    ]
    "question_id" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "option one"
      1 => "option two"
    ]
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "option description"
      1 => "option two description"
    ]
    "description" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "option description"
      1 => "option two description"
    ]
    "question_id" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "option description"
      1 => "option two description"
    ]
  ]
  2 => array:3 [▼
    "title" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "14"
      1 => "14"
    ]
    "description" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "14"
      1 => "14"
    ]
    "question_id" => array:2 [▼
      0 => "14"
      1 => "14"
    ]
  ]
]
```

My form have 3 fields for submit to this model title[],description[],question_id[]
this form is a repeatable form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see you didn't form the html file correctly. Your html file should look like this

```
<input type="text" name="items[1][title]">
<input type="text" name="items[1][description]">
<input type="text" name="items[1][question_id]">

<input type="text" name="items[2][title]">
<input type="text" name="items[2][description]">
<input type="text" name="items[2][question_id]">
```

```
$options = $request->only('items');

$options_data = [];

foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
     $options_data[] = $value;
}

$question->options()->createMany($options_data);
```