# Laravel create multiple records in one query with Eloquent and get the created models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I know I can do the following to create multiple records with one query :

```
$users = [];
$users[] = ['name' => 'Tom'];
$users[] = ['name' => 'Jerry'];

$result = User::insert($users);
```

The problem of this approach is that `ìnsert` uses the query builder, and returns a boolean.

What if I wanted to have the created Eloquent models returned ? Would that be possible without having to do another query to retrieve them (how would I do that since I don't know the created ids ?) ?

I'm looking for something like the `create` method (which returns the created User model), but for multiple inserts (afaik createMany does not work outside of relationships)

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Nite please check following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48472015/saving-multiple-records-in-a-laravel-eloquent-create

Comment: @halilcakar I already read that thread, and have nothing to do with my question unfortunately.

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I missed the part (afaik createMany..) while reading..

Comment: So I was looking for this and saw this proposal on laravel issues which actually denied but this guy wrote a quick dirty way for it https://github.com/laravel/ideas/issues/1695#issuecomment-540745198 maybe something like this works? Or maybe you can tweek the code a bit

Answer (score 0):

I would use Factories to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

How about :

```
$data = [
        ['name' => 'Tom'],
        ['name' => 'Jerry'],
    ];

    $records = collect($data)->map(function ($record) {
        return User::create($record);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert is just for make query which gona make row in database

Instead use "create" function to create object from model, then when all data of object is ready use function "save" to store model object in database

Like

```
foreach($data as $item)
 {
   $userOb = User::create($item);
   $userOb->save();
 }
```