# How can I insert multiple rows to the database in Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I tried to save multiple rows to the database with one query, without success. I used a for loop but it can't retrieve the value of the inputs that are generated using jQuery after setting the number of rows.

**Controller**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $nbrrowsol = $request->get('nbrrowsol');
    for ($i = 1; $i < $nbrrowsol; $i++) {
        $commande = new Commande();
        $commande->nom_client = $request->get('nomclient');
        $commande->organisme = $request->get('organisme');
        $commande->adresse = $request->get('adresse');
        $commande->email = $request->get('email');
        $commande->tel1 = $request->get('tel');
        $commande->tel2 = $request->get('tel2');
        $commande->fax = $request->get('fax');
        $commande->commercial = $request->get('commercial');
        $commande->date_reception = $request->get('datereception');
        $commande->date_prelevement = $request->get('dateprelev');
        $commande->saved_by = $request->get('savedby');
        $commande->code = $request->get('codesol' + $i);
        $commande->nature = $request->get('naturesol' + $i);
        $commande->reference_cli = $request->get('reference_clisol' + $i);
        $commande->profondeur = $request->get('profondeursol' + $i);
        $commande->culture = $request->get('culturesol' + $i);
        $commande->variete = $request->get('varietesol' + $i);
        $commande->gps = $request->get('gpssol' + $i);
        $commande->analyse_demande = $request->get('analysedemandesol' + $i);
        $commande->valide = $request->get('checkvalidee');
        $commande->save();
    }

    return redirect('gestion_commandes/create');
}
```

I get the following error after the user submits for saving data.

> A non-numeric value encountered

I think that I didn't use (for) correctly or the form of:

```
$commande->code = $request->get('codesol' + $i);
```

[image: Error image]

Comment: have you tried passing index to your inputs like, `$request->get('nomclient[ '. $i . ']')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all to concat a string in PHP is done using `.` (dot) notation, not `+`.
So this `'codesol'+$i` should become `'codesol' . $i` and so on for the rest.

If you want to insert multiple rows directly, then take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm) example.

Comment: yes you are right, now the data are registered in the database but only with the value i = 1, the value of i does not increment

Comment: it won't if your `$nbrrowsol` is 2.

Comment: Because you say `$i < 2` which means all below 2, try `$i <= $nbrrowsol`.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You seem to be fetching input using `+` addition operator which is for javascript, in PHP `.` operator is used for concatenation, also you'll need to fetch inputs it using the index of your inputs array, for example when your `<input name="nomClient[]">`

`$request->get('nomclient['. $i . ']')`