# saving data without reloading a page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, laravel

I have a simple form in which a user can fill the form and can add multiple input fields as he/she wishes,

**Here is HTML**

```
  <form id="paramsForms">
                    {{csrf_field()}}
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <dvi class="container h-100">
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">

                                    <div class="card mt-5 col-md-12 animated bounceInDown myForm" id="multiple-container">
                                      <div class="card-header">
                                        <h4>Bidders Information</h4>
                                      </div>
                                      <div class="card-body" id="add_info">
                                          <div id="dynamic_container">

                                          <small id="bidder">Bidder 1</small>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></span>
                                              </div>
                                              <input type="text" placeholder="Bidders Name" name="bidders_name[]" class="form-control"/>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="input-group mt-3">
                                              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fa fa-tags"></i></span>
                                              </div>
                                              <input type="text" placeholder="atribute name" name="params_name[]" id="field1" class="form-control"/>
                                              <input type="number" placeholder="atribute value" name="params_value[]" id="field2"  class="form-control"/>
                                              <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm moreinput_field" id="add_more_input">
                                              <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> 
                                              </a>
                                            </div>
                                          </div>
                                      </div>

                                      <div class="card-footer" id="card-footer">
                                        <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="add_more"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> Add</a>
                                        <!-- <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm float-right submit_btn"><i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> Submit</button> -->
                                      </div>

                                    </div>


                            </div>
                        </dvi>
                    </div>


                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>

                </form>
```

Here is js to save the form

```
 $("#paramsForms").on('submit', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url: "/parameters",
              data: $("#paramsForms").serialize(),
              success: function(response){
                console.log(response)
                alert('data saved');
              },
              error: function(error){
                console.log(error)
                alert('Data not saved');
              }
            })
        })
```

Here is controller store function

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $parameters = new Parameter;

        $parameters->params_name  = $request->input('params_name');
        $parameters->params_value = $request->input('params_name');
        $parameters->bidders_name = $request->input('bidders_name');

        // dd($parameters);

        $parameters->save();
    }
```

The dd($parameters) in-store function gives the following.

[image]

So when I remove `dd($parameters)` and click submit button I get the following error on console (network).

```
message: "Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\roayalad-blog\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php on line 869
```

What is wrong with my codes?

Comment: what is the form HTML? And make these changes and see if error continues:

$parameters->params_name  = $request->input('params_name')[0];
$parameters->params_value = $request->input('params_name')[0];
$parameters->bidders_name = $request->input('bidders_name')[0];

Comment: Looks like the request inputs values are arrays. If it' s intended, you' ll need to loop trough them on your controller to assign just the string value to the model fields. Otherwise, fix it in the frontend, to send a string value on each data key

Comment: @user9964622 your welcome. Please read below answer, give upvote and mark approved if I helped :) thx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are sending `params_name` and `params_name` as an array but controller as handling as strings. Make this change in controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $parameters = new Parameter;

    $record_count = count($request->input('params_name'));

    for($i=0; $i<$record_count; $i++) {
        $parameters->params_name  = $request->input('params_name')[$i];
        $parameters->params_value = $request->input('params_name')[$i];
        $parameters->bidders_name = $request->input('bidders_name')[$i];
        $parameters->save();
    }
}
```

Above code will execute one query each record. You can also do bulk insertion. This is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm).

Comment: But now when the user adds more field inputs and saves It saves only first inputs, do I need to change something_

Comment: made changes in the answer, please check.

Comment: why? check if the code inside for loop is reachable. Put dd() inside for loop.

Comment: okay let me check it again : here is repo https://github.com/throne1986/roayalad-blog  check parameterController

Comment: Did it go inside for loop?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201170/discussion-between-user9964622-and-swaroop-deval).

Answer (score 0):

Try just

```
$request->params_name[$i]
```

Instead of

```
$request->input(“params_name”)[$i]
```