# Here my code to insert multiple records in database on laravel. So, it doesn't work? anyone help me?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to insert multiple records in a table at once submit into a database using eloquent laravel, so I have tried hard.

## my code on controller

```
$x = $request->all();
$datas = DataAnak::create($x)->id_anak;

if ($datas != 0) {
    foreach ($datas as $key => $value) {
        $rows = [
            'nama'             => $request->nama_anak[$key],
            'jenis_kelamin'    => $request->gender_anak[$key],
            'tempat_tgl_lahir' => $request->tmt[$key],
            'tgl_baptis'       => $request->baptis_anak[$key],
            'tgl_sidi'         => $request->sidi_anak[$key],
        ];
        DataAnak::insert($rows);
    }
}
```

## my code on blade page

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="nama_anak[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="gender_anak[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="tmt[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="baptis_anak[]"></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="sidi_anak[]"></td>
    <td class="text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger row-del"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What is `id_anak`?

Comment: PK from **DataAnak** table

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk Insertion in Laravel using eloquent ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm)

Comment: @KiprasT  here the _error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()_

Comment: @TsaiKoga look my code above ' foreach ($datas as $key => $value)'

Comment: `$datas` is PK, why u loop a PK

Comment: @TsaiKoga i have deleted it, but occur the same problem

Comment: can u post your `$x `, I want to know what it is

Comment: @user11974734 Also make sure you have enabled mass insertion in the model.

Comment: I think I need to know about `$x`, because you said you want to insert multiple records, so is your attributes is array?

Comment: @TsaiKoga looked at my code, i declare request data from input on '$x'

Comment: @user11974734 I have posted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$datas = $request->all();
$records = [];
foreach ($datas as $key => $value) {
   $records[][$key] = $value;
}

DataAnak::insert($records);
```

Comment: @summit what sholud i fill on '$records'

Comment: foreach loop will fill the $records in a format acceptable to the insert method.

Answer (score 1):

why are you trying this complex way and that even not the eloquent way to insert data into database. you should do it like below

```
foreach($request->nama_anak as $key => $value){
    DataAnak::create([
        'nama_anak' => $request->nama_anak[$key],
        'gender_anak' => $request->gender_anak[$key],
        'tmt' => $request->tmt[$key],
        'baptis_anak' => $request->baptis_anak[$key],
        'sidi_anak' => $request->sidi_anak[$key],
    ]);
}
```

no need to take the inputs into another variable and create, loop, insert separately.

Comment: i have tried it, it's work but just one record is saved

Comment: then your loop runs only one time. the loop is running based on the input array.

Comment: my input array on blade page is dinamic. i using jquery to add input dan remove it

Comment: ya, length may vary. the loop will run the length time. no problem there. just make sure you are getting the expected lengthen array. try dd($request) and check your inputs.

Comment: i have try insert 3 records, but when try dd($request), just one record is display on array

Comment: then the problem is in your form. check why are you getting only one record.

Comment: Can you suggest me some code how to handle the form to input multiple record.?

Answer (score 0):

So I think your field is array, you need to loop it like this, and insert them at once:

```php
$datas = $request->all();
$rows = array();

foreach ($datas as $key => $data) {
    foreach($data as $index => $value) {
        if ($key == 'nama_anak')   $rows[$index]['nama'] = $value;
        if ($key == 'gender_anak') $rows[$index]['jenis_kelamin'] = $value;
        if ($key == 'tmt')         $rows[$index]['tempat_tgl_lahir'] = $value;
        if ($key == 'baptis_anak') $rows[$index]['tgl_baptis'] = $value;
        if ($key == 'tgl_sidi')    $rows[$index]['sidi_anak'] = $value;
    }
}
DataAnak::insert($rows);
```

*PS: If you have multiple records, don't insert/create them in loop. It will decrease the performance*

Comment: @user11974734 PS: If you have multiple records, don't insert/create them in loop. It will decrease the performance.

Comment: error appear _Invalid argument supplied for foreach()_

Comment: @user11974734 still that problem, what is `$x`, plz post it, so I can know how to get those keys.

Comment: @user11974734 `$x` is the same as `$datas`, so what I means is post the `$request->all()`