# How to optimize large data inserts using laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Good day, basically I want to insert some related data all at once using eloquent. My current code is:

```
$allStudies = Study::chunk(50, function ($studies) use ($request, $questionData, $answerData) {
      foreach ($studies as $study) {
         $evaluationInsert = Evaluation::create([
              'study_id'      => $study->id,
              'questionnaire' => $request->questionnaire,
              'description'   => $request->description
         ]);

         $evaluationQuestions = $evaluationInsert
                                       ->question()
                                       ->createMany($questionData);

         foreach ($evaluationQuestions as $question) {
                  $question->answer()->createMany($answerData);
         }
      }
});
```

The result of `$allStudies` is a collection of `Study` model that currently have around 150-ish data. `$questionData` is just a static array of arrays that consist of 38 elements and `$answerData` is an array of arrays that have 4 elements which consist the answer options of each questions. However, the code does work but it takes too long time to execute because of big loops and increasing the timeout in php seems not an ideal way to solve this. What is the elegant way to solve this kind of case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk Insertion in Laravel using eloquent ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm)

Comment: I think it's different case from mine. My code does work but I always get a timeout exceed error (or warning I forgot) because of the loops I guess.

Comment: ca you use mongo(Jenssegers for Laravel), it is good for large databases, or postgresql which provides asynchronous calls to db.

Comment: "mongo requires lesser input and output operations due to embedded data models, unlike relational databases. MongoDB indexes also support faster queries. " this is the exact statement of comparison between two

Comment: you can visit this link https://blackdeerdev.com/laravel-chunk-vs-cursor/