# How to save multiple records in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

To save 1 data is like this. Should I loop the `->save();` part so I can make 2 or more different columns for each record?

```
$rec = new Record;

$rec->record_id = $id; // multiple ids
$rec->record_name = $name // multiple names

$rec->save();
```

Comment: Please check https://codingdriver.com/how-to-save-multiple-records-in-database-using-laravel.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $mark = new Record();
    $mark->out_of = $data['out_of'];
    if ($data['student_id']) {
        foreach ($data['student_id'] as $row => $value) {
            $data1 = array(
                'out_of' => $mark->out_of,
                'student_id' => $data['student_id'][$row],
                'guardian_id' => $data['guardian_id'][$row],
                'marks_obtained' => $data['marks_obtained'][$row],
                'comment' => $data['comment'][$row],
            );
            Record::create($data1);
        }
    }
    return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'Record Added Successfully');
}
```

in your view

```
<form action="/record/store" method="post">
  @csrf
   <input type="text" name="student_id">
   <input type="text" name="guardian_id[]">
   <input type="text" name="marks_obtained[]">
   <input type="text" name="out_of">
   <input type="text" name="comment[]">
   <button type="submit">Post</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
$rec = [
    ['record_id'=>$id, 'record_name'=>$name],
    ['record_id'=>$id2, 'record_name'=>$name2],
    //...
];

Record::insert($rec);
```

[Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm)