# boot self::creating() not working with insert in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, laravel-models

I want to insert multiple rows using

```
Model::inset($dataArray)
```

but it's not firing boot method.

```
self::creating()
```

Is there any solution ?

I want to insert multiple rows at once to save time but its not calling laravel observer method self::creating().

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `insert()` does not trigger any events in the model. I believe you should use `create()` or `save()`

Comment: @Techno Thanks for your reply. Is there any way to insert multiple rows at once using create() ?

Comment: Yes, please check KGG's answer as it is spot on :)

Comment: @Techno My apologies, wasn't intending to highjack the answer, I didn't see the comments so I will delete my answer, please post yours.

Comment: No please, keep it

Comment: But thanks for the offer ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk Insertion in Laravel using eloquent ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702812/bulk-insertion-in-laravel-using-eloquent-orm)

Answer (score 3):

Use **createMany** to achieve this on relationShips:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

If you want to do this on the model directly, you can just create the function:

**ExampleModel:**

```
public static function createMany($records){
    foreach($records as $record) {
        $this->create($record);
    }
}
```

*If you look at the create() function in the model:*
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;

```
    /**
     * Save a new model and return the instance.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|$this
     */
    public function create(array $attributes = [])
    {
        return tap($this->newModelInstance($attributes), function ($instance) {
            $instance->save();
        });
    }
```

it uses the **save()** function that dispatches the event `"creating"`: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#events

**Save()** will call `$this->performInsert($query)`

and

**performInsert** does `$this->fireModelEvent('creating')` as well as `$this->updateTimestamps()`

---

As **@Techno** mentioned: [https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts:~:text=When%20issuing%20a,a%20mass%20update](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts:%7E:text=When%20issuing%20a,a%20mass%20update)

[image: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts:~:text=When%20issuing%20a,a%20mass%20update]

Comment: Its for relationships

Comment: @SajjadAli you can accomplish this by making your own method if its not for relationships like the above

Comment: @SajjadAli, maybe you can share which relationship you want to add it to? I think KGG can update the answer to reflect just that :)

Comment: this will run multiple insert queries which I want to avoid.

Comment: @SajjadAli check my explanation, it does fire the event creating :)

Comment: @SajjadAli, maybe this helps explain why it is unavoidable: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#upserts:~:text=When%20issuing%20a,a%20mass%20update.