# Query with multiple where statements?

Tags: php, mysqli

Having an issue with changing a value in "table1" from "table2" with the [INSERT INTO SELECT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) Statement. Which copies the table2 into table1.

Let me explain...

Where you see the **`AND group_name = 'djsfshj'`** in the SELECT statement of table2 below... I need that value (djsfshj) to be placed into "table1" but when I run my code table1 doesn't add anything. It kinda ignores it and I get no errors. If I remove `AND group_name = 'djsfshj'` my code works but then the group_name will be blank.

It's blowing my mind how I can't get this to work. Any idea why this is happening? Any help is appreciated!

**Code:**

```
foreach ($_GET["users_slideshows"] as $users_pick) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (username, volume, name, image, content, cssanimate, group_name) 

SELECT '".$user_data['data']['username']."', volume, name, image, content, cssanimate, group_name
        FROM table2 WHERE volume IN ('".$users_pick."') AND group_name = 'djsfshj' ";

        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }

}
```

Comment: Does the select statement itself return any rows?

Comment: It seems weird that you'd specify `$user_data['data']['username']` in your SELECT statement where you are defining columns.  Shouldn't that just be the name of your column, and not the username value?

Comment: @RobertC I thought also but it is in the select statement, so OK. Of course it should be in a parametrized query

Comment: "If you remove group_name"... interesting... You should check if rows with a given volume has the group_name you want. Like @aynber said, you should check the SELECT statement alone in a DB manager (phpMyadmin,...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [PHP's join](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.join.php) to put the content of the variable `$_GET["users_slideshows"]` as comma separated values

```
$users_pick = join(',',$_GET["users_slideshows"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

i see that your quotations inside the query are not accurate, can you try :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (username, volume, name, image, content, cssanimate, group_name) ";
foreach ($_GET["users_slideshows"] as $users_pick) {
$sql .= "SELECT ".$user_data['data']['username'].", volume, name, image, content, cssanimate, group_name
        FROM table2 WHERE volume IN ('".$users_pick."') AND group_name = 'djsfshj' ";
}


        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "";
        } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
```

Comment: Foreach will continuously add the `$sql` string ! Imagine if you have 3 elements in the array ! You should do `$sql2 = $sql . "SELECT...` and query `$sql2`

Comment: this way it will perform a bulk insert as in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html, also its right this way .. check the answer on how to do bulk insert on foreach here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10615762/php-bulk-insert-foreach

Comment: Your linked answer works with `(...,...)` INSERT style. `SELECT` is used here, it could work but with `UNION` between each `SELECT`

Comment: Oops exactly you are Right!

Comment: Also the query must be outside of the `foreach` loop

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment guys! @Goufalite this wouldn't work for me